# Flake8 does not produce errors

Tags: python, flake8

Flake8 does not produce error on E121,E123,E126,E226.

When I run `flake8 --help`, I get back:

```
--ignore=errors       Comma-separated list of errors and warnings to ignore
                        (or skip). For example, ``--ignore=E4,E51,W234``.
                        (Default: E121,E123,E126,E226,E24,E704,W503,W504)
```

I did check if there is any file at `.config/flake8`, but it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Flake8 is not producing those errors because they are ignored by default (as is explained in the help text for `--ignore` that you copied and pasted above).